# How to show this function is unbounded below?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, upper-lower-bounds

I have the following convex optimisation problem that I really do know how to prove is unbounded below.

> minimise $\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i - \Sigma_{i=1}^{n} \beta_i$
>
> subject to $y_i[\Sigma_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_j y_j x_i^t x_j - b] = \beta_i - \alpha_i$
>
> $0 \le \lambda_j \le 1, \alpha_i \ge 0, \beta_i \ge 0, \space \space  i,j=1,...,n $

The inputs to this problem are pairs of $(x_i, y_i)$ which $x_i \in R^d, \space \space y_i \in \{1, -1\}$. The variables of this problem are $\alpha_i, \beta_i, \lambda_i, b$ where $i, j = 1, ..., j$.

I should mention that I've seen [Prove this function is unbounded below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2257713/487106)
 and more specifically the first and second paragraphs of the answer which explain the conditions to satisfy in order to show a function is unbounded below, but about my case, I can not handle it. Can anyone help me?

I should also mention the provided problem is a bit like Support Vector Machine in machine learning, but is different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primal problem can be rewritten into
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cl}
{\min} & {f(\lambda, b)=-\sum_{i=1}^n y_i [\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j y_j x_i^{T} x_j - b]} \\
{\text{s.t.}} & {0 \leq \lambda_j \leq 1, \quad j=1,\dots,n} \\
{} & {b \in R.}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
And we can reformulate $f(\lambda, b)$ as
\begin{equation}
f(\lambda,b) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \right) b - \sum_{i=1}^n y_i x_i^T \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j y_j x_j
\end{equation}
Since $\lambda_j$ is bounded, the second term of function $f(\lambda, b)$ is bounded. 
Thus $f(\lambda, b)$ is unbounded below unless 
\begin{equation}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \right) \neq 0.
\end{equation}
In other words, the optimization problem is unbounded below if $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \right) \neq 0$. Otherwise, we can attain a finite optimal value.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating *Since $\lambda_j$ is bounded, the function  is unbounded below unless*

Comment: @Media I have edited my answer. And the second term of $f(\lambda, b)$ is linear of $\lambda$, thus it is bounded because $\lambda$ is bounded. So the unboundedness of $f(\lambda, b)$ can be determined by the first term.